# Tabbar dissapears when removing item in UITabBarController

Tags: ios

I have defined an scene with a tab bar controller in my main storyboard.
I want to programmatically remove one tab.
If I execute this code in the UITabBarController class viewDidLoad method

```
self.viewControllers!.remove(at: 1)
```

the tabbar is removed completely from the screen.
Why could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Problem was that I was trying to remove a tab in the viewDidLoad method. I placed the code in the viewWillAppear and it worked fine.